# BERT-R How to hide some functions from users?

Tags: r, excel, bert-toolkit

Is it possible to hide functions from being shown in excel but that exist in the functions.R file?  At the moment all functions are exposed to excel as R functions but I would like to be able to select which functions are exposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BERT exposes all functions from the global environment. If you want to have functions in the console but not in Excel, put them in a separate environment (you can `attach` it so they're in the global namespace).

For example, in the functions file

```
visible.func <- function(){ 100 }

console.env <- new.env();
with( console.env, {

   hidden.func <- function(){ 200 }

});
attach(console.env);
```

then `visible.func` will be visible in both R and Excel, while `hidden.func` will only be visible in the console.

Just be aware of the consequences of things being in different environments.

Why do it this way, and not the reverse (have a special environment for Excel functions)? Because the primary use-case is for Excel functions, so that one is the default.